# Submit fields added through javascript to the request object

Tags: jquery, django, django-forms

What I am trying to do is, I am adding an author's field through javascript when the user clicks on the icon contained in the span. But the problem is that the fields added through javascript on submission of the form are neither obtained in the form object nor the request.POST object.
I have two problems mainly:

1. I want to be able to pass the values to the server in the fields added through javascript and be able to access them in the views.py
2. I also want to know if there is some neater way to do it.

views.py

```
def addbook(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        print(request.POST)
        form=BookForm(request.POST)
        # process accordingly.
    else:
        form = BookForm()
        return render(request,'book.html',{'form':form})
```

forms.py

```
class BookForm(forms.Form):
    author_name=forms.CharField(max_length=20)
```

book.html

```
<form action='' method="POST">
    <div id='authorfield'>{{ form.author_name }}</div>
    <a href='#'><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
</form>
```

book.js

```
$('span').click( function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#authorfield").after(" <div><input type='text' class='form-control' placeholder='Author name'></div>");

});
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to have a `name` attribute in the `input` element that is added by your JS.

However I'm not sure this will do what you want; you already have an author_name field, so it's not clear why you want to add another one.

Comment: I want to be able to have as many field for author_name as the user wants (there could be more than one author too) and adding a name field is also a problem since name has to be unique and two fields added by user will then have same names. 
Also if i add name attribute will i be able to access it in views.py then?

Comment: Sounds like you are really looking for [formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/formsets/).

Comment: "I want to be able to have as many field for author_name as the user wants (there could be more than one author too)" => then your model is wrong - you should have an `Author` model and a many to many relation with `Book`.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers my author field is already many to many field but if i use that field in my form as model form then i get a scroll down list to select the already enetered authors..and i want the user to be able to enter the list of authors...anyways I solved this problem in some other way.